# Different colors for boxplot outlines and overlaying lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with boxplots by group and lines connecting the medians for each group. I'm trying to set different colors for the boxplot outlines compared to the lines (and make the boxplot more transparent than the lines):

```
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=year, y=var)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=scn, color=scn), outlier.alpha=0.2, outlier.size=1, alpha=0.3) +
  stat_summary(fun=median, geom="line", aes(group=scn, color=scn), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  stat_summary(fun=median, geom="point", aes(group=scn, color=scn), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#31b03e","#4287f5","#ba8d45","#d6ca58"),
                     labels=c("SCN1","SCN2","SCN3","SCN4")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("palegreen","slategray2","navajowhite2","lightyellow2"),
                    labels=c("SCN1","SCN2","SCN3","SCN4")) +
  labs(fill="Scenario", y="Discharge", x="Year") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(colour=NA, fill=NA), axis.text.x=element_text(angle=0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("00","10","20","30","40"))

p
```

[image]

Is there a way to add a 3rd scale_color_manual? I tried with a custom name following https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html but without success as it seems I cannot find a proper complete example how to achieve that.

The data used:

```
structure(list(n = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2021L, 2022L, 2023L, 
2024L, 2025L, 2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 2030L, 2031L, 2032L, 
2033L, 2034L, 2035L, 2036L, 2037L, 2038L, 2039L, 2040L, 2041L, 
2042L, 2043L, 2044L, 2045L, 2046L, 2047L, 2048L, 2049L, 2050L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2021L, 2022L, 2023L, 2024L, 2025L, 2026L, 
2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 2030L, 2031L, 2032L, 2033L, 2034L, 2035L, 
2036L, 2037L, 2038L, 2039L, 2040L, 2041L, 2042L, 2043L, 2044L, 
2045L, 2046L, 2047L, 2048L, 2049L, 2050L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 
2021L, 2022L, 2023L, 2024L, 2025L, 2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 
2030L, 2031L, 2032L, 2033L, 2034L, 2035L, 2036L, 2037L, 2038L, 
2039L, 2040L, 2041L, 2042L, 2043L, 2044L, 2045L, 2046L, 2047L, 
2048L, 2049L, 2050L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2021L, 2022L, 2023L, 
2024L, 2025L, 2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 2030L, 2031L, 2032L, 
2033L, 2034L, 2035L, 2036L, 2037L, 2038L, 2039L, 2040L, 2041L, 
2042L, 2043L, 2044L, 2045L, 2046L, 2047L, 2048L, 2049L, 2050L
), var = c(49.1842988, 50.9389673, 58.7667795, 52.3864965, 67.7012817, 
45.83866885, 56.2058055, 53.218841, 43.63990345, 54.57564125, 
50.47714685, 57.0244025, 53.3796562, 52.7796321, 38.6241609, 
46.5878751, 55.9013598, 56.86939895, 49.22260655, 51.0736213, 
68.4324329, 57.3720771, 45.7441465, 72.89368645, 38.8482276, 
37.9131649, 45.75653875, 53.9466447, 56.18402075, 52.52772265, 
37.482211, 59.5808889, 59.07940935, 76.94199435, 43.1966639, 
64.69970585, 44.352438, 49.5407952, 76.93041265, 50.3561565, 
48.74177165, 47.45165555, 50.2770307, 46.35246395, 41.5503569, 
53.34283045, 65.41014805, 49.7071029, 55.6300862, 56.4481931, 
55.51490425, 47.2961528, 48.3943343, 55.109132, 48.427613, 63.1769827, 
41.61334385, 51.7496265, 48.2665625, 39.6494865, 48.89401075, 
43.63118695, 50.8736475, 48.98305425, 46.86977165, 35.3884648, 
41.4073946, 48.0812644, 48.01022395, 43.2892629, 43.0274143, 
58.6908309, 48.0709866, 38.9168429, 60.44348895, 32.94504265, 
32.1918272, 37.8174966, 43.72269785, 46.0787548, 43.56473225, 
31.6066777, 45.7625129, 46.44064685, 57.48937935, 34.4025266, 
50.83714285, 35.4565744, 37.0871176, 56.34632315, 38.77242915, 
36.53227825, 36.01607035, 39.29295825, 36.7151525, 33.04551575, 
38.6756474, 48.1210093, 36.8555369, 42.1249647, 41.73702585, 
39.33565025, 49.59750705, 50.83765635, 59.219641, 51.912016, 
66.3376012, 45.21114845, 54.9513523, 36.8642144, 64.945192, 34.46018225, 
56.7070712, 50.847303, 72.1469515, 39.6138548, 42.281798, 49.16150655, 
72.2328035, 47.0207777, 45.00446665, 68.9821496, 67.875262, 40.69574015, 
54.1759517, 68.851107, 71.24442, 57.6633616, 60.4905353, 63.6455287, 
50.14464845, 46.3555794, 55.96746545, 65.41214875, 42.8507664, 
36.01196885, 66.19647515, 58.7056093, 68.3744698, 54.87278615, 
50.3113468, 74.706216, 52.34141705, 68.55676685, 72.60430255, 
64.27464875, 63.2033896, 64.57905285, 67.14832735, 66.05586065, 
66.712321, 52.4162067, 51.27488405, 47.34502955, 48.68440785, 
54.986997, 48.765782, 62.8207307, 41.84512995, 50.9004483, 34.4748872, 
58.098183, 31.1362675, 50.6645282, 46.2696143, 64.347179, 35.9832005, 
36.47467135, 43.23627555, 63.2424845, 40.7043312, 38.68227935, 
59.8394121, 55.786523, 34.05867725, 45.7618317, 58.034756, 58.809374, 
48.9853026, 49.2571118, 52.5463393, 39.99541845, 37.8807884, 
45.1287915, 52.54199925, 33.77909405, 29.3564999, 51.90838315, 
47.8799763, 52.3458468, 43.07931615, 39.0721188, 56.901442, 38.16054125, 
51.75514435, 55.9980291, 46.69136225, 42.7510616, 46.93113685, 
51.26968535, 49.48515065, 47.796229, 40.66684375, 35.9056581), 
    year = c("00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
    "00", "00", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
    "10", "10", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", 
    "20", "20", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", 
    "30", "30", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", 
    "40", "40", "40", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
    "00", "00", "00", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
    "10", "10", "10", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", 
    "20", "20", "20", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", 
    "30", "30", "30", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", 
    "40", "40", "40", "40", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
    "00", "00", "00", "00", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
    "10", "10", "10", "10", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", 
    "20", "20", "20", "20", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", 
    "30", "30", "30", "30", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", 
    "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
    "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
    "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", 
    "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", 
    "30", "30", "30", "30", "30", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", 
    "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40"), scn = c("scn_26_c1", 
    "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", 
    "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", 
    "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", 
    "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", 
    "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", 
    "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", 
    "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", 
    "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", 
    "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", 
    "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", "scn_26_c1", 
    "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", 
    "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", 
    "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", 
    "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", 
    "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", 
    "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", 
    "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", 
    "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", 
    "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", 
    "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", "scn_26_c2", 
    "scn_26_c2", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", 
    "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", 
    "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", 
    "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", 
    "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", 
    "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", 
    "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", 
    "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", 
    "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", 
    "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", 
    "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c1", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", 
    "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", 
    "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", 
    "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", 
    "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", 
    "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", 
    "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", 
    "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", 
    "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", 
    "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", 
    "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2", "scn_85_c2")), row.names = c(NA, 
-204L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(d)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: You bet! Try the package `ggnewscale`.